# What is happening inside a built in function?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, dll

This is my first question, I had read the instructions in the ask page, will try to follow them. But I'm not sure is this the right site to ask this question. anyway let me describe my requirement.

While debugging we can step into a method by pressing `F11` and see what is happening(how the method processing our inputs and produce output)inside the method. or else we can use `F12` key to go to the definition of the method and can check what are all the code they used to perform the action. I would like to do the same to built in .Net(c#) methods.

> For example: I'm calling `Directory.CreateDirectory` method to create
>   a directory in the specific path. But when I press `F12` which will
>   show me the `Meta Data` instead for the specific function definition.

So my question here is, Is there any possibility to see the code that used by microsoft to build these builtin functions, either through debugging or through go to definition?

Comment: I don't think it is that easy, you may be able to step through built in functions, but not see the c# code. but if you only want to see how those components are written you can download the [source code of .NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html) from Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Gist of it is that you need to disable "Just my code" debugging at Tools>Options>Debugging>General.

Comment: actually it should be disabled.